# GWT + RequestFactory + RequestContext Overloading Validation

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I am having issues with regarding the overloading of the Request Context.

I have the following:

```
public interface TaskAssignmentRequest extends RequestContext {
.
.
.

    Request<List<TaskAssignmentProxy>> findTaskAssignmentByProjectIds(List<String> id);

    Request<List<TaskAssignmentProxy>> findTaskAssignmentByProjectIds(List<String> id, Date start_date, Date end_date);
```

I am getting the following errors when I am running my code

```
SEVERE: Method overloads found in type com.abc.server.TaskAssignmentService named findTaskAssignmentByProjectId:
  java.util.List findTaskAssignmentByProjectId(java.lang.String java.util.Date java.util.Date )
  java.util.List findTaskAssignmentByProjectId(java.lang.String )
```

Is overloading not allowed in this case?  I do not see why not.

Thanks,

Nadin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequestFactory doesn't currently (as of GWT 2.2) support method overloads in service APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that those are the only methods it could find, when it's looking for the methods with the `List<String>` parameter?  The methods you've listed just have a plain String for the first parameter.